# Prove that $\|f\|_{L^r}\leq \|f\|_{L^p}^\alpha \|f\|_{L^q}^{1-\alpha }$ if $\frac{1}{r}=\frac{\alpha }{p}+\frac{1-\alpha }{q}$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

How can I prove that $$\|f\|_{L^r}\leq \|f\|_{L^p}^\alpha \|f\|_{L^q}^{1-\alpha }$$ if $\alpha \in[0,1]$, $\frac{1}{r}=\frac{\alpha }{p}+\frac{1-\alpha }{q}$ and $f\in L^p\cap L^q$. It looks to be something with Holder, but I can' conclude.

Comment: [this is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2421496/if-frac1p-frac1q-frac1r-then-fg-lr-leq-f-lp-g) same type of question, isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can show using Hölder's inequality that if $r,p,q\in [1,\infty]$ with 
$$ \frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}, $$
then
$$ \|fg\|_{L^r}\le \|f\|_{L^p}\|g\|_{L^q} $$
for every $f\in L^p$, $g\in L^q$. Now, since we are given 
$$ \frac{1}{r} = \frac{\alpha}{p} + \frac{1-\alpha}{q} = \frac{1}{p/\alpha} + \frac{1}{q/(1-\alpha)}, $$
applying the result I just mentioned yields
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{L^r} = \|f^\alpha f^{1-\alpha}\|_{L^r} & \le \|f^\alpha\|_{L^{p/\alpha}}\|f^{1-\alpha}\|_{L^{q/(1-\alpha)}} \\
& = \left(\int |f^\alpha|^{p/\alpha}\right)^{\alpha/p}\left(\int |f^{1-\alpha}|^{q/(1-\alpha)}\right)^{(1-\alpha)/q} \\
& = \|f\|_{L^p}^\alpha\|f\|_{L^q}^{1-\alpha}
\end{align*}
for any $f\in L^p\cap L^q$.